# Checking null while parsing Instagram API in swift

Tags: ios, null, nsdictionary

I'm trying to parse Instagram API, in some dictionaries like caption contains null value. which cause app crashes. I tried all possible solutions available on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.
The question is how to check if NSDictionary have null value in swift?

Following is the Code:

```
var captionDict: NSDictionary! = firstObject.objectForKey("caption") as NSDictionary!   // this causing the error when caption: null
        if (captionDict != nil) || (captionDict != NSNull()) {
            var captiontext = captionDict.objectForKey("text") as String!
            if captiontext != nil {
                objInstaFeed.captionText = firstObject.objectForKey("caption")?.objectForKey("text") as String!
            } else {
                objInstaFeed.captionText = ""
            }
        } else {
            objInstaFeed.captionText = ""
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you're looking for is:

```
if var captionDict = firstObject.objectForKey("caption") as? NSDictionary {
  ....
}
```

`as?` is used to optionally downcast. When you run the code above if the object returned by `firstObject.objectForKey("caption")` can be typecast to an `NSDictionary` then the `captionDict` variable will be set (the compiler will infer the type as `NSDictionary`) and you'll go into the if statement. If it can't be typecast to an `NSDictionary` (for instance if it is an instance of `NSNull`) then the typecast will fail and the if statement won't be entered.

There is also a similar operator `as!` this is used to forcefully downcast, if you use this and the downcast fails then it will crash your application.

Comment: would you please explain it briefly?

Answer (score 0):

For `NSNull` you can check like this-

```
var value: AnyObject! = firstObject.objectForKey("caption")   // this causing the error when caption: null
if (value != nil) && !(value.isEqual(NSNull()))
```